# Javascript: Synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

** Newbie to Javascript. Please help **

I am writing a simple 'for' loop in Javascript and I am not getting the expected output. Request help.

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i + ": " + makeARestCall(options));
}

function makeARestCall(options) {
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    let test = getCount(body);
    console.log("Hello: " + test);
  });
}

function getCount(body) {
  const data = JSON.parse(body.toString()).test.all;
  return data;
}
```

makeARestCall(options) - function makes a Rest call to a service and gets some data.
getCount(body) - returns a value from the JSON received from makeARestCall function.

How am I executing: Writing a Mocha Test using Javascript.

What is the current output:

```
1: undefined
2: undefined
3: undefined
4: undefined
Hello: 35
Hello: 35
Hello: 35
Hello: 35
```

What am I expecting?

```
1: Hello: 35
2: Hello: 35
3: Hello: 35
4: Hello: 35
```

It appears 'for' loop runs so quickly and makeARestcall takes time to execute because it takes couple of seconds for execution. Please help on how I can get the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request` runs *asynchronously*, not synchronously, and `makeARestCall` does not return anything currently. You should probably have `makeARestCall` return a *promise* which is then consumed in the `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  makeARestCall(options)
    .then(responseStr => console.log(i + ': ' + responseStr));
}

function makeARestCall(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      let test = getCount(body);
      resolve("Hello: " + test);
    });
  });
}
```

Make sure to use `let i` and not `var` or no declaration at all, else `i` will be hoisted to the outer block and will have the same value (5) once all the requests come back. (Try to avoid implicitly creating global variables)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Promise is a new concept for me. This greatly helps and I will read more on promise..